# Prolog: I keep getting errors when trying to compile a simple program

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm trying to make a simple grammar parser that checks whether a specific sentence pattern is valid or not. the grammar rules are as follows:

terminals: circleplus, circleor, 1, 0

non-terminals: S; T

start symbol: S

production rules: S --> S circleplus T | S circleor T | T, and: T --> 0 | 1

```
sentence([]).
sentence([a, b, c|Tail]) :- checkHead(a), checkC(b), checkT(c), sentenceCheck(Tail).

sentenceCheck([]).
sentenceCheck([b, c|Tail]) :- checkC(b), checkT(c), sentenceCheck(Tail).


checkT(c) :- T(c).
checkC(b) :- C(b).
checkHead(a) :- Head(a).

C(circleor).
C(circleplus).
Head(0).
Head(1).
T(0).
T (1).



% ?- sentence ([[0 , circleor ,1] , circleplus ,1]) .
%       ==> true
```

The bottom comments are what a sample input --> output would look like.
Appreciate any help.

EDIT: (per response to my question)

```
sentence([]).
sentence([A, B, C|Tail]) :- checkHead(A), checkC(B), checkT(C), sentenceCheck(Tail).

sentenceCheck([]).
sentenceCheck([B, C|Tail]) :- checkC(B), checkT(C), sentenceCheck(Tail).


checkT(C) :- t(C).
checkC(B) :- c(B).
checkHead(A) :- head(A).

c(circleor).
c(circleplus).
head(0).
head(1).
t(0).
t(1).
```

Only now the query `sentence([0, circleor, 1]).` returns `false` when it should be `true`. Any ideas?

Comment: You have edit your question, just as I answered. Should I edit my answer or will it suffice?

Comment: It will suffice, I'll change it to what you have since it's cleaner and more along the rules of Prolog :)

Answer (score 1):

In prolog variables start with a capital letter and constant terms start with a lowercase letter. You are getting the error because prolog expects the predicate to be a constant term rather than a variable.

```
sentence([]).
sentence([A, B, C|Tail]) :- checkHead(A), checkC(B), checkT(C), sentenceCheck(Tail).

sentenceCheck([]).
sentenceCheck([B, C|Tail]) :- checkC(B), checkT(C), sentenceCheck(Tail).


checkT(C) :- t(C).
checkC(B) :- c(B).
checkHead(A) :- head(A).

c(circleor).
c(circleplus).
head(0).
head(1).
t(0).
t(1).
```

The above changes will help but your sample input, output will not work as you are nesting the list. If you do not nest the list as follows it will work.

```
?- sentence([0, circleor, 1, circleplus, 1]).
true.
```

A solution even when the input is not flattened is :

```
sentence(A) :- t(A).
sentence([A, B, C]) :-
    sentence(A),
    c(B),
    t(C).

c(circleor).
c(circleplus).
t(0).
t(1).
```

Comment: I had no idea they had to be capitalized, also I think I was fixing my code while you were responding, lol, so I got it sort of working now, but it's not working for nested lists unfortunately, which unfortunately I kinda need. I thought the `sentenceCheck(Tail)` would work for that, no?

Comment: @ESM : Give me a few more samples of how you need it to work.

Comment: `sentence ([])` = true, `sentence ([[0 , circleor ,1] , circleplus ,1]) .` = true, `sentence ([[[0 , circleplus ,0] , circleor ,1] , circleplus ,1]) .` = true, and `sentence ([[[0 , circleplus ,0] , circleor ,[1 , circleor ,0]] , circleplus ,1]) .` = false

Comment: @ESM : Your code just checks for double nesting. It wont work for any deeper ones. You need a more general recursive parser.

Comment: Don't the lines `sentenceCheck([]).` and 
`sentenceCheck([B, C|Tail]) :- checkC(B), checkT(C), sentenceCheck(Tail).` take care of the recursion? Because it's calling itself until it's empty?

Comment: @ESM : yes it does. The current solution works if you stop nesting lists in the input.

Comment: @ESM: your solution assumes that everything is left associative and in a flattened list. If you want to distinguish between them then you need a general recursive parser.

Comment: @ESM : do you want `((0 and 0) and (0 and 0))` to fail and `(((0 and 0) and 0) and 0)` to pass?

Comment: I think the 2nd one is more correct.
I was thinking that in `checkSentenc(Tail)` I could do `is Tails empty ? return [], else return checkSentence(Tail)`
Is there a way to check if Tails is empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224610/discussion-between-rajashekar-and-esm).